# Meaning of “accumulation through mar­ket exchanges”?

Tags: monetary-policy, definition

I'm unsure as to whether this question belongs on the History or Economics stack exchange, but while reading a book on Soviet Union policies after WW1 I came across the term “accumulation through mar­ket exchanges”. The context is:

The story of the Left-Right-Center debates during the 1920s is complex. The positions of the protagonists some­ times clashed: for example, in economics the ‘primitive ac­ cumulation” thesis versus the “accumulation through mar­ket exchanges” proposition; or, in ideology, the possibility versus impossibility of building socialism in one country.

Could someone explain this term or provide some resources that I could use to educate myself?(A google search yields nothing immediately fruitful) For explaining purposes, consider me as someone with roughly a year of high school economics class experience.

Comment: Could you please provide reference to where you heard the term?

Comment: On a very basic level, the language is used to express a distinction between perceived 'involuntary' and 'voluntary' economic activity. With the former, 'primitive accumulation' is a Marxist term referring to something close to wealth made by a slave-owning class. The latter term refers to economic activity where wealth is generated through the exchange of labour for money, and likewise, money for the final production/consumption good (all of which, exchanged on a set of markets).